# Refer to a variable start with @ from json in php

Tags: php, json

Hi I know that I can refer to json variable after decoding in php using this following way:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$myfile = fopen("aaaa.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $data->form->variable);
fclose($myfile);
```

However, there is a variable starts with @ in json.
how do I refer to that variable?
`$data->form->@name` doesn't work and `$data->form['@name']` doesn't work either.

here is my json file: (I want the @name)

```
{
    "build_id": "d776ccf19c994f65b8605ecc0711d94b", 
    "archived": false, 
    "uiversion": "1", 
    "attachments": {}, 
    "form": {
        "@uiVersion": "1", 
        "@xmlns": "http://openrosa.org/formdesigner/77618A3E-48A4-474D-9AC5-80D7BFA952F7", 
        "@name": "External Good Receiving Note", 
        "Truck_num": "f", 
        "invoice_num": "fd", 
        "#type": "data", 
        "driver_signature": "", 
        "arrival_time": "2017-05-22T19:31:00.000000Z", 
        "driver_name": "f", 
        "meta": {
            "@xmlns": "http://openrosa.org/jr/xforms", 
            "app_build_version": 118, 
            "commcare_version": "2.35.3", 
            "instanceID": "8e895f2c-30c6-4ba9-979c-e99af9f4ad1c", 
            "username": "wang", 
            "userID": "306dd277c96773330613bfa78005a596", 
            "appVersion": "CommCare Android, version \"2.35.3\"(431724). App v118. CommCare Version 2.35. Build 431724, built on: 2017-04-19", 
            "timeEnd": "2017-05-22T19:31:48.042000Z", 
            "timeStart": "2017-05-22T19:31:26.109000Z", 
            "geo_point": null, 
            "deviceID": "352331080741542"
        }, 
        "officer": "ff", 
        "Signature": "", 
        "waybill_num": "f", 
        "warehouse_code": "ff", 
        "@version": "118", 
        "PO": "15", 
        "comment": "ff", 
        "name": {
            "@xmlns": "grn"
        }
    }, 
    "initial_processing_complete": true, 
    "received_on": "2017-05-22T19:31:48.170284Z", 
    "app_id": "0d24ecddaf46a8516780a7ab32b1d120", 
    "is_phone_submission": "2.0", 
    "version": "118", 
    "domain": "crs-emergency-response-system", 
    "problem": null, 
    "resource_uri": "", 
    "type": "data", 
    "id": "8e895f2c-30c6-4ba9-979c-e99af9f4ad1c", 
    "metadata": {
        "app_build_version": 118, 
        "doc_type": "Metadata", 
        "commcare_version": "2.35.3", 
        "instanceID": "8e895f2c-30c6-4ba9-979c-e99af9f4ad1c", 
        "deprecatedID": null, 
        "username": "wang", 
        "userID": "306dd277c96773330613bfa78005a596", 
        "appVersion": "CommCare Android, version \"2.35.3\"(431724). App v118. CommCare Version 2.35. Build 431724, built on: 2017-04-19", 
        "timeEnd": "2017-05-22T19:31:48.042000", 
        "timeStart": "2017-05-22T19:31:26.109000", 
        "geo_point": null, 
        "deviceID": "352331080741542", 
        "location": null
    }
}
```

The file after json_decode, it still has @ symbol before those variables:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [app_id] => 0d24ecddaf46a8516780a7ab32b1d120
    [archived] => 
    [attachments] => stdClass Object
        (
        )

    [build_id] => d776ccf19c994f65b8605ecc0711d94b
    [domain] => crs-emergency-response-system
    [form] => stdClass Object
        (
            [#type] => data
            [@name] => External Good Receiving Note
            [@uiVersion] => 1
            [@version] => 118
            [@xmlns] => http://openrosa.org/formdesigner/77618A3E-48A4-474D-9AC5-80D7BFA952F7
            [PO] => 15
            [Signature] => 
            [Truck_num] => f
            [arrival_time] => 2017-05-22T19:31:00.000000Z
            [comment] => ff
            [driver_name] => f
            [driver_signature] => 
            [invoice_num] => fd
            [meta] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [@xmlns] => http://openrosa.org/jr/xforms
                    [appVersion] => CommCare Android, version "2.35.3"(431724). App v118. CommCare Version 2.35. Build 431724, built on: 2017-04-19
                    [app_build_version] => 118
                    [commcare_version] => 2.35.3
                    [deviceID] => 352331080741542
                    [geo_point] => 
                    [instanceID] => 8e895f2c-30c6-4ba9-979c-e99af9f4ad1c
                    [timeEnd] => 2017-05-22T19:31:48.042000Z
                    [timeStart] => 2017-05-22T19:31:26.109000Z
                    [userID] => 306dd277c96773330613bfa78005a596
                    [username] => wang
                )

            [name] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [@xmlns] => grn
                )

            [officer] => ff
            [warehouse_code] => ff
            [waybill_num] => f
        )

    [id] => 8e895f2c-30c6-4ba9-979c-e99af9f4ad1c
    [initial_processing_complete] => 1
    [is_phone_submission] => 2.0
    [metadata] => stdClass Object
        (
            [appVersion] => CommCare Android, version "2.35.3"(431724). App v118. CommCare Version 2.35. Build 431724, built on: 2017-04-19
            [app_build_version] => 118
            [commcare_version] => 2.35.3
            [deprecatedID] => 
            [deviceID] => 352331080741542
            [doc_type] => Metadata
            [geo_point] => 
            [instanceID] => 8e895f2c-30c6-4ba9-979c-e99af9f4ad1c
            [location] => 
            [timeEnd] => 2017-05-22T19:31:48.042000
            [timeStart] => 2017-05-22T19:31:26.109000
            [userID] => 306dd277c96773330613bfa78005a596
            [username] => wang
        )

    [problem] => 
    [received_on] => 2017-05-22T19:31:48.170284Z
    [resource_uri] => 
    [type] => data
    [uiversion] => 1
    [version] => 118
)
```

Comment: Show us your JSON example, I never heard any json with keys that has `@` or any kind of special character...

Comment: Can you please show your json?

Comment: edited, pasted json file here@AlivetoDie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go:

```
$a = ['@name' => 'test'];
$json = json_encode($a);
$o = json_decode($json);

echo $o->{'@name'}; // outputs "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution would be to use this

```
$data->form->{'@name'}
```